# Using AJAX to Interface with an oscilloscope on a Local Network

Tags: php, ajax, oscilloscope

I'm trying to interface with an oscilloscope networked to IP address 192.168.1.1. It has a built in web-server that, for lack of better words, sucks. It has tons of `iframe`s and only fully works in IE. I'm in the process of building an open-source web application that can easily interface with oscilloscopes and display waveforms with HighcartsJS in real-time.

Anyway, I'm trying to run this code in Internet Explorer (even though I want to run it in Chrome) with no luck:

```
REMOVED BECAUSE IT HAD SILLY MISTAKES
```

When I open the file in Internet Explorer I do see that the URL is rewritten to localhost even though localhost is NOT 192.168.1.1. Typing in localhost brings me to my local web server (so I'm open to using PHP to do this POST if I can figure it out).

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Here's the TCP Stream from Wireshark:

```
POST /Comm.html HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: 192.168.1.1/Comm.html
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 192.168.1.1
Content-Length: 38
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
COMMAND=CURVe?
gpibsend=Send
name=
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MIME-Version: 1.0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: TUE --
Content-Length: 8506
<HTML>..NUMBERS/HTML CUT OUT TO SAVE SPACE....22,22,22,2</HTML>
```

CONCLUSION SO FAR: I realized I had multiple problems with my code. However, this works:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'link',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        data: {command: 'BEL',
                gpibsend: 'Send'},
    })
```

But this doesn't: I'm trying to read the response as detailed in the TCP trace:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://192.168.1.1/Comm.html',
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        data: {command: 'ZOOM:HORIZONTAL:SCALE?',
                gpibsend: 'Send'},
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data)
        }
    })
```

Comment: +1 for "It has tons of iFrames and only fully works in IE." Wow. Sorry.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the debugger (F12)?  I know with IE, even a `console.log` error will stop javascript.

Comment: This may or may not help you ..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213502/how-to-deploy-a-php-application-on-a-lan

Comment: Also, your HTML doesn't have a `DOCTYPE` declaration, which should be used, especially with IE.  And you have different IP's in your AJAX call from the form action.

Comment: `jQuery` is used but not called?

Comment: form action is 192.168.1.2, ajax call is 192.168.1.1 Intentional?

Comment: Cross-domain restrictions may apply...

Answer (score 0):

Most of browsers will not allow to use ajax call to go to other servers that the origin of that script. So that in your script seems to be wrong.

On other hand I don't understand why to even You specify the whole IP address of server. Usually pointing to a file that should return answer should be just fine.

Another thing, what king of webserver do run on that Oscilloscope. I do ask cause they are not a common machine to find, especially with a webserver.

Also if you want a real time updates, don't use AJAX. Use websockets. You see, Ajax is basically a call to a webserver just like calling a website, and that process is very long when we want to make an application that will have to get data very fast. Thus, wise people did invented WebSocket API for use in browsers. You see, socket is a direct connection and cause of that You will have to implement a protocol of your own. But for use to communicate with a oscilloscope that would probably mean to make a server file that hacks to internal software, and will just spit numbers every 0.1 s. JS will catch those numbers and will just add another data to result table, and repaint the whole plot.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of "server" runs on it but I did a packet analysis on the request that works from Internet Explorer. Is there anyway I can execute this from localhost? Here it is:

Comment: posted in original post because of the comment code character limit

Comment: Ok. Your first snippet is going to http://hostname/link, so it is pointing to something that do some computing, thus You have an output. In second snippet you are pointing to html file, so in that lovely alert that you call should be all that html. Still, I don't know what you are trying to achieve now...

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to follow up on this in case anyone comes across this on Google. There are multiple options here:

1. Host the website on a domain, edit your hosts file and point a sub-domain of your website's domain to the LAN IP address
2. Create a VPN and access all machines from static IP addresses
3. Run your browser with security features disabled
4. If you can change the domain name server on the oscilloscope then host your own DNS and resolve any given address to the LAN connection
5. Run a LAMP/WAMP server on your computer and make the calls via AJAX through PHP (from the server)